# Change Gnome preferred applications without installing Gnome?

Tags: linux, gnome, kde-plasma

I'm using KDE, but I also use some GTK applications.  When those GTK apps make a call to an external program, they use the preferred applications set for Gnome rather than the ones I've set.

One example is Gimp.  From the Help menu, if I select anything from "GIMP Online" it opens the information in the *default* web browser.  In KDE, my default web browser is Mozilla Firefox, but GTK applications open Opera.

Installing the `gnome-control-center` package would probably solve the problem, but that introduces a lot of unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either install gconf-editor/dconf-editor and edit the relevant keys, or use the command-line tool to edit them.

Use the `gconftool-2` to lookup and set the values. See on `/desktop/gnome/applications` and levels below for the right keys to change.

You can get a list of keys with:

```
gconftool-2 -R /desktop/gnome/applications
```

See the gconftool-2 help pages for how to set the values to keys.

Comment: Thanks for answering this old question.  I actually gave up and installed Gnome, even though I only use it for changing Gnome/GTK settings.  On my Kubuntu system, gconftool-2 is provided by the gconf2 package.